# how to run query in access that the field Contains the char '

Tags: c#, ms-access

i need to connect to customer database in access that contains field with the char `'`

he has field: `PartNo'`

i try to run this query: `select PartNo' from myTable`

and got error.

(i connect to the database and run query Through C#)

how i can Solve this problem ? (i can't change the customer table's and field's)

thank's in advance

Answer (score 5, accepted):

put brackets around the table or field name:

```
select [PartNo'] from myTable
```

In some other SQL dialects it's double quotes:

```
select "PartNo'" from myTable
```

In still other dialects, you can use backquotes:

```
select `PartNo'` from myTable
```

Hopefully one of these works for you.

Comment: Option 1 is the only one that applies to Access/Jet/ACE. Option 2 in Access will "work" but it will give you the literal string "PartNo'" in every row of the results, not the data from the field with that name.

Comment: Hmm, maybe I'm thinking Oracle then on the second option. Thanks for the feedback. The answer has been slightly updated.